# Зачем нужны миграции?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Зачем их придумали, если можно вместе с исходниками выкидывать дамп?

Чувствую, что вопрос наитупейший ^^ тапками не кидайте.

Comment: Что подразумевается под миграциями?

Comment: Версионность базы, структуры, записей. http://habrahabr.ru/post/121265/

Comment: А, это. Ну например что-бы новый код не попытался работать со старой версией данных (попортив их или просто выдав неверный результат), что-бы старый код не сделал то-же самое с новой версией. Что-бы в принципе понимать какая тут версия данных и нужно-ли её обновлять или она уже обновлённая. Представь что существует более одного экземпляра кода и БД и обновить их все разом это долго.

Не всегда-ведь можно остановить программу (сервис), обновить код, обновить структуру БД, проверить что всё соответствует и аккуратненько запустить.

Зачем вообще люди придумали версионирование?

Comment: Банальная простота обновления\отката, обычно удобный ООП стиль описание команд (вставка, удаление, обновление, пр.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего миграцию используют для правильного переезда базы на новую структуру. В проектах часто бывает, что раньше все шли по одной структуре, а потом существующую базу надо переделать, но данные потерять никак нельзя. Для этого используют миграцию.

Answer (score 3):

**Миграция**, в данном контексте, — изменение структуры базы данных от одной версии до другой (обычно более новой).

Поэтому предлагаю в случаях, когда контекст неочевиден, использовать более точный термин: ***версионная миграция баз данных***.

**Зачем это нужно?**

Версия базы данных должна соответствовать версии приложения. Это — неразрывные части одного целого. Это означает, что при поставке новой версии приложения в продакшн, нужно обязательно обновлять и версию базы данных, иначе приложение попросту не сможет правильно работать.

Вот тут хороший полный ответ, который даст пищу для размышлений:
[Версионная миграция структуры базы данных: основные подходы](https://habr.com/ru/post/121265/?_ga=2.267361866.573864575.1583310511-1755378498.1583310511)

Comment: Хорошо бы основное перенести в ответ.

Comment: И желательно не затягивать. После голосования участников по качеству сообщения, оно может попасть под удаление.