# Есть ли менеджеры SQL с возможностью создавать патчи для обновления базы?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Предположим, есть у меня программка на python использующая базу SQLite или MySql. Программка используется на нескольких базах. Я хочу в своей копии сделать изменения базы под новые свойства, и эти изменение получить в виде патчей к прежним версиям, с учетом что некоторые установки могут пропускать обновления. Или сразу как запрос на создание всех таблиц - если это будет новая установка этой программы. У 1С примерно подобный механизм, но мне для SQL, для использования с python или других ЯП.

Какие варианты существуют по такому управлению БД?

Comment: Это называется [миграции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/325882), и по этому слову гуглится много всякой информации

Comment: @andreymal Вроде то, что нужно. Спасибо. Буду изучать тему.